# Corpus bleu score calculation

Tags: math, calculation, machine-translation, bleu

I am trying to calculate bleu score text summarization. Before that I need to know how corpus bleu calculates score between given references and a candidate. I have 3 references and 2 candidates where I am calling corpus bleu on first two references with candidate 1 and reference 3 with candidate 2. What kind of math is involved? Like does it take the average or geometric mean , what is it? 
It would be helpful if someone shows the calculation